# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-5.7

I need to update my Ubuntu server 16.04 to 18.04 maintaining my current MySQL 5.7 database (it is about 600Gb).
If I do `do-release-upgrade` also MySQL will be updated to 5.8, and I don't want this.
MySQL community 5.8 does not support partitioning as a free feature.

Comment: there is no 5.8

Comment: you mean mysql8 right ?

Comment: run this scenrario in a vm i doubt that an upgrade will upgrade your mysql

Comment: Downvoted b/c it has zero to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

1. backup if it's not done.
2. use docker to run the desired version on MySQL and bring your data in it (you will not be dependent on ubuntu packages anymore) :

`docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.7`

3. profit